# @PathVariable Validation in Spring 4

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-data

How can i validate my path variable in spring. I want to validate id field, since its only single field i do not want to move to a Pojo

```
@RestController
public class MyController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ResponseEntity method_name(@PathVariable String id) {
        /// Some code
    }
}
```

I tried doing adding validation to the path variable but its still not working

```
    @RestController
    @Validated
public class MyController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ResponseEntity method_name(
            @Valid 
            @Nonnull  
            @Size(max = 2, min = 1, message = "name should have between 1 and 10 characters") 
            @PathVariable String id) {
    /// Some code
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no path variable in your code at least not in your URL so not sure what needs to be validated...

Comment: Sorry i missed it while copy & pasting the code here

Comment: You can try simple if loop in method_name method like if(id==null || id.length()<1 || id.length()>2){ String message = "name should have between 1 and 10 characters"; } and you can return ResponseEntity as per your requirement if loop turns out to be true,

Comment: @R.A.S. does any of the answers helps you? Or is there another solution/problem?

Comment: Thanks Patrick, Your solution worked

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to create a bean in your Spring configuration:

```
 @Bean
    public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
         return new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
    }
```

You should leave the `@Validated` annotation on your controller.

And you need an Exceptionhandler in your `MyController` class to handle the`ConstraintViolationException` :

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = { ConstraintViolationException.class })
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public String handleResourceNotFoundException(ConstraintViolationException e) {
         Set<ConstraintViolation<?>> violations = e.getConstraintViolations();
         StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
         for (ConstraintViolation<?> violation : violations ) {
              strBuilder.append(violation.getMessage() + "\n");
         }
         return strBuilder.toString();
    }
```

After those changes you should see your message when the validation hits.

P.S.: I just tried it with your `@Size` validation.

Comment: I tried your solution but it doesn't seem to work. Only difference is that I have GET method. Is that handled separately?

Comment: @NickDiv no should be the same. What is not working for you? Maybe you should raise a question and comment the link of it here.

Comment: @Patrick: Could you provide the full source code for this, I tried but It's still failed to validate PathVariable

Answer (score 0):

To archive this goal I have apply this workaround for getting a response message equals to a real `Validator`:

```
@GetMapping("/check/email/{email:" + Constants.LOGIN_REGEX + "}")
@Timed
public ResponseEntity isValidEmail(@Email @PathVariable(value = "email") String email) {
    return userService.getUserByEmail(email).map(user -> {
        Problem problem = Problem.builder()
            .withType(ErrorConstants.CONSTRAINT_VIOLATION_TYPE)
            .withTitle("Method argument not valid")
            .withStatus(Status.BAD_REQUEST)
            .with("message", ErrorConstants.ERR_VALIDATION)
            .with("fieldErrors", Arrays.asList(new FieldErrorVM("", "isValidEmail.email", "not unique")))
            .build();
        return new ResponseEntity(problem, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }).orElse(
        new ResponseEntity(new UtilsValidatorResponse(EMAIL_VALIDA), HttpStatus.OK)
    );
}
```