# Spring REST Service Controller not being validate by @PathVariable and @Valid

Tags: spring, rest, validation

```
@Controller
@EnableWebMvc
@Validated
public class ChildController extends ParentController<InterfaceController> implements InterfaceController{

    @Override
    @RequestMapping(value = "/map/{name}", produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseStatus( HttpStatus.OK)
    @ResponseBody   
    public List<Friends> getAllFriendsByName(
        @Valid
        @Size(max = 2, min = 1, message = "name should have between 1 and 10 characters")
        @PathVariable("name") String name,
        @RequestParam(value="pageSize", required=false) String pageSize,
        @RequestParam(value="pageNumber", required=false) String pageNumber,            
        HttpServletRequest request) throws BasicException {

    //Some logic over here;

    return results;
    }

@ExceptionHandler(value = { ConstraintViolationException.class })
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public String handleResourceNotFoundException(ConstraintViolationException e) {
    Set<ConstraintViolation<?>> violations = e.getConstraintViolations();
    StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (ConstraintViolation<?> violation : violations ) {
        strBuilder.append(violation.getMessage() + "\n");
    }
    return strBuilder.toString();
}
```

Hi, I am trying to do pretty basic validation for a spring request parameter but it just doesn't seem to call the Exception handler, could someone point me into the right direction

P.S. I keep getting NoHandlerFoundException

Answer (score 1):

Spring doesn't support `@PathVariable` to be validated using `@Valid`. However, you can do custom validation in your handler method or if you insist on using `@Valid` then write a custom editor, convert your path variable value to an object, use JSR 303 bean validation and then use @Valid on that object. That might actually work.

**Edit:**
Here's a third approach. You can actually trick spring to treat your path variable as a model attribute and then validate it. 
1. Write a custom validator for your path variable
2. Construct a `@ModelAttribute` for your path variable and then use `@Validator` (yes not `@Valid` as it doesn't let you specify a validator) on that model attribute.

```
@Component
public class NameValidator implements Validator {
    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return String.class.equals(clazz);
    }
    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        String name = (String) target;
        if(!StringUtils.isValidName(name)) {
            errors.reject("name.invalid.format");
        }
    }
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/path/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Friend> getAllFriendsByName(@ModelAttribute("name") @Validated(NameValidator.class) String name) {
    // your code

    return friends;
}

@ModelAttribute("name")
private String nameAsModelAttribute(@PathVariable String name) {
    return name;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by Custom Editor. And isnt @ Size a JSR303 annotation

Comment: I meant a `PropertyEditor` or `org.springframework.format.Formatter.Formatter` to convert your path variable into a regular bean and yes you're right `@Size` is a JSR 303 annotation. You see path variable is part of the actual URL so spring assumes it to be naturally valid but still if you want to validate, those are your options.

Comment: Does that mean this example or answer is wrong.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35403744/pathvariable-validation-in-spring-4

Comment: I like the third approach, but lets say I have one more method in my controller called as getById then how would I use same validator to validate the value. Now id would have to go through another kind of validation. Would it be possible that validator can be dynamic that it would validate based on filed passed to ModelAttribute