# Add class level validation to @Pathvariable in Spring

Tags: java, spring, rest, validation, spring-mvc

I have done a lot of research and tried a lot of solutions available before posting this question.

Here is the tricky situation I am stuck in.

I have a Spring controller that has multiple request mappings and they all have @PathVariables

Here is what Controller looks like:

```
@Controller
@EnableWebMvc
public class ChildController extends ParentController<InterfaceController> implements InterfaceController{

    @Override
    @RequestMapping(value = "/map/{name}", produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseStatus( HttpStatus.OK)
    @ResponseBody   
    public List<Friends> getAllFriendsByName(
        @PathVariable("name") String name,
        @RequestParam(value="pageSize", required=false) String pageSize,
        @RequestParam(value="pageNumber", required=false) String pageNumber,            
        HttpServletRequest request) throws BasicException {

    //Some logic over here;

    return results;
    }

@Override
    @RequestMapping(value = "/map/{id}", produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseStatus( HttpStatus.OK)
    @ResponseBody   
    public List<Friends> getAllFriendsById(
        @PathVariable("id") String id,
        @RequestParam(value="pageSize", required=false) String pageSize,
        @RequestParam(value="pageNumber", required=false) String pageNumber,            
        HttpServletRequest request) throws BasicException {

    //Some logic over here;

    return results;
    }

}
```

Now I have recently learned that you cannot validate a Path Variable in Spring, and contrary to these examples which I have tried it turns out that it does not work
(Examples tried: [@PathVariable Validation in Spring 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35403744/pathvariable-validation-in-spring-4))

So I thought of adding a custom JSR303 constraint validation to my path variables and create something of my own like

```
 import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE;
 import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;
 import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
 import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
 import java.lang.annotation.Target;
 import javax.validation.Constraint;
 import javax.validation.Payload;

 @Target({ TYPE})
 @Retention(RUNTIME)
 @Constraint(validatedBy = PathVariableValidator.class)
 @Documented
 public @interface RequestValidationNeeded {

String id();

String name();

Class<?>[] constraints() default {};

Class<?>[] groups() default {};

Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

String message() default "totally wrong, dude!";

 }
```

This is not my original idea its inspired from this post
http://techblogs4u.blogspot.ca/2012/09/method-parameter-validation-in-spring-3.html

What I am not able to figure out is how I will map @RequestValidationNeeded annotation to both PathVriables i.e. `id` and `name` and call the same validator and based on which field is calling the validator invoke the appropriate validation.

I do not like this way but my options have exhausted and this is the last thing that I could think of that might work but even for this I need to figure out a way to annotate both path variables with same annotation and call same validator.

I would appreciate any kind of help or direction on this.

Some other questions that I have posted based on what I have tried might help you understand better what validations I have tried.

P.S. I am posting links instead of the code just to keep the question short.

Links: 
[How to make customEditor in Spring dynamic enough to call validation on appropriate methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37849617/how-to-make-customeditor-in-spring-dynamic-enough-to-call-validation-on-appropri)

[Spring REST Service Controller not being validate by @PathVariable and @Valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37849150/spring-rest-service-controller-not-being-validate-by-pathvariable-and-valid)

Comment: In the solution provided by Patrick (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35403744/pathvariable-validation-in-spring-4) he told specifically to add @Validated annotation to the controller and also add @Size annotation to your path variable, for example: ```@PathVariable("name") @Size(min=1, max=10) String name```. Then add remaining code from his post and see if it works. It should.

Comment: @R4J I did try that. The code that is posted is my local code, not the one that I tried. I did add the @ Validated and added the @ Size validation as well.