# spring boot @PathVariable can not validate

Tags: spring, validation, spring-boot

yeah, the same question as [@PathVariable Validation in Spring 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35403744/pathvariable-validation-in-spring-4) and [Add class level validation to @Pathvariable in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37850812/add-class-level-validation-to-pathvariable-in-spring?noredirect=1&lq=1)

spring validated not work for param, throw no exception, here is my code follow by @Patrick's answer, thx for him

```
@Bean
public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
     return new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
}

/**
 * 
 * @param accountId
 */
@RequestMapping(value="/orderDetailSelByAccountId/{accountId}.json",method= {RequestMethod.POST})
@ResponseBody
@Validated
public Result<?> orderDetailSelByAccountId(  @NotNull @NotBlank 
@Size(min=10,max=32)@PathVariable(value="accountId") String accountId) { ....    }
```

but when I send null accountId, there are no exception throws...
am I right, are there anyother solutions?

Comment: i think  `@Validated` should go as class level annotation according to the links you provide in the question

Comment: still not work..............

Comment: You can validate it manually when request received in the controller. If validation failed, then send a error message. I think this should be better approach.

Comment: my project have a exception center, it can catch all exception in boot project, so I think the better way is use annotation and in the exception center to handle all the valid error

Comment: According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19430770/3064489) and the related [issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-6380) the annotation isn't supported for `@PathVariable` at the moment.

Comment: @DanielMüssig thx, It's seems not work. what your suggestion? am I have to write some custom annotations to handle it? or  use some other solutions?

Comment: Personally, I don't like to do the validation thing at endpoint level. Endpoints are suppose to just expose the service layer. Validation, checking, and business logic should be delegated to the service layer. So if you will transfer the validation thing to the service interface method, annotate the service implementation class with `@Validated`, then it should work the way you want it to.

Answer (score 9):

Add the following annotation to the **class** worked for me.(Not to the **method**)

```
@Validated
```

Answer (score 3):

I know the question is quite old but just stumbled across the same issue with Spring Boot v2.4.5. All other responses are correct to some extinct I'd like to bring more clarity here.
As correctly mentioned by [subin-chalil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2756662/subin-chalil) `@Validated` has to be placed on the class level, processing of this annotation is done by `MethodValidationPostProcessor` which brings us to answer by [mafei](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12553450/mafei).
However with Spring Boot you can basically add a corresponding implementation as a dependency so that it could make it's way to the classpath.
For example adding:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Enabled validation logic for following snippet

```
@Validated
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = GreetingResource.BASE_PATH)
public class GreetingResource {

     static final String BASE_PATH = "/greet";
     static final String HELLO_PATH = "/hello";

    @GetMapping
    @RequestMapping(path = HELLO_PATH + "/{name}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Map<String, String> greet(@Size(min = 1, max = 5) @PathVariable String name) {
        return Collections.singletonMap("response", String.format("Hi %s !", name));
    }
```

Processing of GET request: `/greet/hello/Testyy` resulted in `javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException`:

```
{"timestamp":"2021-05-10T15:13:05.863+00:00","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","trace":"javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: greet.name: size must be between 1 and 5 ...
```

Comment: By luck I came across this answer! I was missing the dependency in my pom.xml file

Answer (score 2):

set a bean called MethodValidationPostProcessor

```
@Bean
public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
     return new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
}
```

and set @Validated into your controller class,

```
@Validated
```

and then if, you want catch them properly in controller advice put this code in your controller advice.

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = {
    ConstraintViolationException.class
})
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public String handleResourceNotFoundException(ConstraintViolationException e) {
    Set < ConstraintViolation << ? >> violations = e.getConstraintViolations();
    StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (ConstraintViolation << ? > violation : violations) {
        strBuilder.append(violation.getMessage() + "\n");
    }
    return strBuilder.toString();
}
```