# How to validate @PathVariable with custom validator annotation containing repository bean

Tags: java, spring

I know how to validate `@PathVariable` from https://stackoverflow.com/a/35404423/4800811
and it worked as expected with standard annotations but not with the customized one using a Repository bean. Maybe the bean is not initialized and I end up with `NullPointerException` when accessing the end point has `@PathVariable` validated. So how to get that work?

My Controller:

```
@RestController
@Validated
public class CustomerGroupController {
    @PutMapping(value = "/deactive/{id}")
    public HttpEntity<UpdateResult> deactive(@PathVariable @CustomerGroupEmpty String id) {

    }
}
```

My custom validator:

```
public class CustomerGroupEmptyValidator implements ConstraintValidator<CustomerGroupEmpty, String>{
    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository repository;

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        // NullPointerException here (repository == null)
        if (value!=null && !repository.existsByCustomerGroup(value)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

}

My Custom Annotation:

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = CustomerGroupEmptyValidator.class)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface CustomerGroupEmpty {
    String message() default "The customer group is not empty.";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload> [] payload() default {};
}
```

Comment: I would suggest using `@InitBinder` and `WebDatabinder` to have custom validators for validating request params/ path variables. Refer: https://www.concretepage.com/spring/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-validator-with-initbinder-webdatabinder-registercustomeditor-example

Comment: @Kunal the link is broken

Answer (score 2):

code in this post is correct, only mistake is that validator need to override initialize method as well. Probably user123 incorrect configure repository bean, the simply way to check this is define it manually in configuration class